# How to show a link text without a link layout?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

On my website I wanna jump to another page by clicking on a name. That works fine. But I want to show the name under the same class-definitions. No blue text and no underline. How do you that?

```
    <td class="titel_artiest"> <%: item.Titel%><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a class="titel_artiest" href="<%= Url.Action("Index", "Hitdossier", new { AArtiest =  item.Artiest }, null) %>"><%: item.Artiest %></a></td>
```

[image]

Comment: have you added any css?

Comment: I think my question was not clear enough. But I use the received answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a css-problem, not a C# one.

Just edit the relevant css for the site to include something like this:

```
a.titel_artiest { 
     text-decoration:none: 
     color: #000; // replace with correct color
     // etc
}
```

Note the `a.` here - your problem is probably that you currently have some other element type (like `div`, `span` or `ul`) defined for the styling of class `titel_artiest`, but not the link-tag `a`.

Comment: No I want to the same layout as the <td>-class but I couldn't find how. But I have defined an extra class for links, as your example. This is good enough for me. I know that the titel_artiest is defined as a <td>-class and for <a>.